# React: Content of Drawer is not rendered on state change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Drawer component (not persistent, only opens on button click) of  Material UI within a child component, where I want to show a list of notifications. The notifications are loaded from a server and passed from the parent component.

I can verify that the data is updated on state change and the render method below is called. Also the .map() method is called correctly. But the content of the drawer stays empty. 
It obviously works when using a bunch of static listItems, but not when using map() based on a list.
My guess is that is has something to do with the Drawer not being shown, when the update occurs. But it should be possible to add dynamic data to a Drawer, right? What am I missing here?

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
render() {
    return (
        <Drawer>
            <List>
                {this.props.notifications.map((n, key) => {
                <ListItem key={key}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Info/>
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText inset primary={n.header} secondary={n.message}/>
                </ListItem>
                })}
            </List>
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```

Comment: do you modify `notifications` in parent component, then pass it as props?

Comment: yes, exactly. in parent I load it from server and then pass it to child: <NotificationList notifications={this.state.notifications}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I tried to use componentWillReceiveProps() and set the state of my child component, but unfortunately it didn't help. The notifications do get updated in child component, but it still didn't render the new ListItems.

However, in the meanwhile I did manage to solve it. At least this works for me. So here's my solution for future reference. I had to extract the mapping into a separate function:

```
const mapItem = (notifications) => {
    return notifications.map((n, key) => (
        <ListItem key={key}>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <Info/>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText inset primary={n.header} secondary={n.message}/>
        </ListItem>
    ));
};
```

And then use it like this in the render method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Drawer>
            <List>
                {mapItem(this.props.notifications)}
            </List>
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```

This works, but I honestly can't say why resp. why it doesn't the other way around. Seems like List expects a constant list of ListItems, before it gets rendered. So if anyone has an explanation for this behaviour, I would gladly hear it.

Answer (score 0):

So when you pass props

```
 <NotificationList notifications={this.state.notifications}>
```

It is true that `this.state.notifications` are getting modified in parent component. Once your render method of parent component invokes; it renders all child components as well. So the props in child component will stay as it was rendered initially until you ask it on demand.

To get modified in child components you can use 
[componentWillReceiveProps()](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html/%22componentWillReceiveProps()%22)

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(props){
   console.log(props.notifications) //this will get you modified bits.
   this.setState({notifications:props.notifications});
 }
```

And in render of child component

```
{this.state.notifications.map((n, key) => {
                <ListItem key={key}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Info/>
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText inset primary={n.header} secondary={n.message}/>
                </ListItem>
 })}
```

Also make sure you initialize `notifications` in child component state as well

```
construction(props){
 super(props);

    this.state = {
     notifications : []
    }
}
```